# how to select the dropdown value

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Not able to select the job value in artifact dropdown .

[image: Artifact dropdown]

DOM

[image: Dom values]

CODE I HAVE TRIED

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='artefact-type'][@type='text']")).click();

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
 act.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.DOWN,Keys.ENTER)).perform();

Actions builder =new Actions(driver);
WebElement ele1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'job')]"));

builder.moveToElement(ele1).build().perform();

Thread.sleep(2000);

builder.click(ele1).build().perform();
builder.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.DOWN,Keys.DOWN,Keys.ENTER)).perform();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Please add html sample (not a screenshot) and info about what did you try? what error did you get? It will help to suggest the right way

Answer (score 0):

U need to use "Select" class to select drop down values.
and u can use any method from selectbyvalue , selectbyindex or selectbyvisibletext.

Just need to create object for `Select` class as follows:

```
Select type = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("artefact-type")));
type.selectByIndex(1);
```

Comment: hey debanjanb ,as in dom we don't have select class ,it start with input autocomplete tag,even i also tried with select class got unexceptedTagname exception

Comment: @Bharat This is not my answer. I have simply indented the lines of code for proper reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"))).selectByVisibleText("text");
```

By using this u can inspect "dropdown" and also select their value.

Answer (score 0):

new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"))).selectByIndex(Index Number);

Use this for selecting the drop down values